# Creating a table dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, createelement

I am trying to create a table dynamically as soon as a page loads. In the code below, I get a response when I click the button, but the table is not displayed on the page. What's wrong with the code below? I have looked at other discussion threads on this topic, but none have helped.

The code in the Javascript file is as follows:

```
    function showalert() {
            alert('what?');
    }

    function displayGuides() {
            var mgdCell, mgdRow, mgdTable;

      mgdTable = document.createElement('table');
      mgdRow = mgdTable.insertRow(0);
      mgdCell = mgdRow.insertCell(0);
      mgdCell.innerHTML = "1111";
      mgdCell = mgdRow.insertCell(1);
      mgdCell.innerHTML = "2222";
      mgdCell = mgdRow.insertCell(2);
      mgdCell.innerHTML = "3333";
      mgdCell = mgdRow.insertCell(3);
      mgdCell.innerHTML = "4444";
      mgdCell = mgdRow.insertCell(4);
      mgdCell.innerHTML = "5555";
      document.getElementByID('mgdTable').appendChild(mgdTable);
    }

    function mgdUserActions() {
      var create = document.getElementById('create');
      create.onclick = showalert;
      displayGuides();
    }

    window.onload = mgdUserActions;
```

Comment: always check your javascript console for errors please, and post those errors if u get any. ok, now i got it right: just change `displayTable;` to `displayTable();`

Comment: Well, for one, this isn't the best way to build a table dynamically. Try using templates, like Mustache or Handlebars.

Comment: I am trying to display the table as soon as the page loads. I don't need the user to click the button to display the table.

Comment: right. i saw that too late. but your code should work as far as i can see. **check your javascript console for errors if it doesn't**

Answer (score 2):

Your call in displayGuides to `document.getElementByID` should be `document.getElementById`. The 'D' in `ID` should be 'd' `Id`.

[Check out the fiddle of awesomeness](http://jsfiddle.net/rpsZ5/)

Comment: Thank you, Ryaminal. The code worked after I made the change you suggested. My Javascript coding skills are a bit rusty, and I wasted a day on debugging this :-(

Comment: @AnilBhat Glad it worked. I found it by hitting F12 and Chrome's Developer Tools magically told me the exact problem. :)